# Declare Function in a class library dependency

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I use Azure Functions extensively, and I've been trying do develop some kind of common utilities library for using in Functions projects. I am also attempting do declare some common useful functions that I use accross many projects. As an example, this is a DbLog Activity function for logging in orchestration methods:

```
[FunctionName(LoggingFunctionNames.DbLog)]
public static void Run([ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context)
{
    var input = context.GetInput<DbLogInput>();
    Write(input); // writes to database
}
```

The issue is I wasn't able to make my project identify Functions declared outside itself. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not documented [*yet*](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/commit/101e4ced4fa5d489883a45bf28821df42064dd65). You can set the `FunctionsInDependencies` property in your `csproj` file which scans dependencies for functions to load as well.

This was brought up in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62800977/10417839).